# Roslyn project's didn't load after cloning the source code from github

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

I cloned the whole source code of roslyn from github.

When I open a solution, like Roslyn.sln or Samples.sln, many projects couldn't be loaded and I get an error displayed in the output window for every project that couldn't be loaded.

> Error:
>   The imported project "BASEPATH.nuget\packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools\14.2.25201\build\Microsoft.VsSDK.BuildTools.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  BASEPATH\Source\Repos\roslyn\build\Targets\Settings.targets

I use VS 2015 U2 enterprise edition.

I hope that there is somebody that can help to get the issue fixed.

Comment: Have you followed the exact steps as mentioned in their wiki? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Contributing-Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run the Restore.cmd script in the root folder before you can open in Visual Studio. You should read our [instructions for building](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Building%20Testing%20and%20Debugging).

Comment: Thank you very much Jason. I restored the whole project with the restore with batch and the most of the projects could be loaded. Unvailble projects could be loaded using the context menu command,(install missing Features). I' try later to build the solution. Again many thanks. Yazid

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy a roslyn file out of one of your other projects and past it in your bin folder clean and rebuild and you will be all set